# Adding new actor skin and animation in Gazebo

Tags: gazebo

I want to add a new skin and animation to Gazebo.

I created a model in blender and export it to Gazebo.
Everything works:
https://streamable.com/z2utvh

Here is the `.dae` file which works:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1K3JZy9nuojmmzbxlJ3XOvKoCPy0GyOxB/view?usp=sharing

However, I can't change the size (pressed <kbd>s</kbd> to scale the model in Blender). After I made the model smaller in Blender and export (collada .dae file) it to gazebo again, it didn't work anymore:

https://streamable.com/21cqoi

Here is the .dae file which don't work:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/19CNp_Rv2vt0w5vxK4rbohNlHPJIKmlF5/view?usp=sharing

This is my .world file:

```
<!-- A global light source -->
<include>
  <uri>model://sun</uri>
    <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
</include>

<!-- A ground plane -->
<include>
  <uri>model://ground_plane</uri>
  <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
</include>

<scene>
  <ambient>0.4 0.4 0.4 1</ambient>
  <background>0.25 0.25 0.25 1</background>
  <shadows>false</shadows>
</scene>
<light type="directional" name="some_light">
  <diffuse>0.7 0.7 0.7 0</diffuse>
  <specular>1 1 1 0</specular>
  <direction>-1 -1 -1</direction>
</light>    

<actor name="actor1">
  <pose>0 0 1.2138 0 0 0</pose>

  <skin>
    <filename>model://Kid/meshes/kids.dae</filename>
  <scale>1.0</scale>
  </skin>

  <animation name="walking">
    <filename>model://Kid/meshes/kids.dae</filename>
    <scale>1.000000</scale>
    <interpolate_x>true</interpolate_x>
  </animation>

</actor>
```

Do I have to change something else?

Maybe in the .dae file?

I tried different things but nothings works.

I would be really grateful if someone could help me.